# SSH tunneling remote host port into Vagrant guest VM

Tags: mysql, ssh, virtual-machine, vagrant

The database I'm working with is too large to fit on my computer, hence too large to fit in Vagrant VM. I'd like to be able to connect to MySQL database server from Vagrant guest VM. MySQL is restricted to connections from localhost.

One way would be tunnel MySQL using ssh -L to my computer and to set up private network in Vagrant (https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/private_network.html). However is it possible to just "vagrant up" and have SSH tunnel created?

Comment: How about putting your private network setup commands in a bash script and editing your Vagrantfile to execute the script? https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html